# Linear functionals, covectors and one-forms

Tags: linear-algebra

According to Wikipedia:

"In linear algebra, a **linear functional** or **linear form** (also called a **one-form** or **covector**) is a linear map from a vector space to its field of scalars."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form

Is this accurate? I mean, can we say that "linear functional", "covector" and "one-form" are synonyms?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'd say "covector" and "$1$-form" typically refer to functionals on a tangent space to a manifold / something else with a notion of tangent space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say they are synonyms, just as the words **function**, **map**, and **transformation** all generally refer to the same thing. Sometimes it's just a matter of context whether one synonym will be preferred over the other, for example, as G. Sassatelli mentions. In my experience, "one-form" will be used generally when you are talking about exterior algebra things, for example when dealing with differential forms on a manifold. I'm not too sure about the difference in usages between the other two, however.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the terms are completely equivalent in the linear algebra context. As just pointed out in the previous answer, the terms can have a more specific meaning in different contexts. For example when one talks about 'one-form'on a *manifold*, the 'one-form' is actually a map that assign to each point of the manifold a covector on the tangent space (i.e. a linear map on the tangent space), in other words it is a collection of linear maps on different vector spaces.